# Long title into <ion-card-title> truncated

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an `<ion-card>` with a `<ion-card-content>` and an `<ion-card-title>` inside of it.
The problem is that when the title of the card it's too long, it's truncated (as shown in the image)

[image]

I would like to be able to see the entire title, so if the title it's too long, it should go in the next line like this:

[image]

How can I do it??

This is my code

```
<ion-card>
      <button ion-item (click)="openPlace(item)">
            <img src="assets/img/fontanamasini.jpg"/>
            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-card-title  style="font-size:20px"> {{item.myPoi.nome}}</ion-card-title >
              <ion-list *ngFor="let tag of item.tipo"> <p>{{tag} </p> </ion-list>
            </ion-card-content>
       </button> 
</ion-card>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`text-wrap`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#text-alignment) in `ion-card-title` for this.

```
<ion-card>
      <button ion-item (click)="openPlace(item)">
            <img src="assets/img/fontanamasini.jpg"/>
            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-card-title text-wrap style="font-size:20px"> {{item.myPoi.nome}}</ion-card-title >
              <ion-list *ngFor="let tag of item.tipo"> <p>{{tag} </p> </ion-list>
            </ion-card-content>
       </button> 
</ion-card>
```

Check the [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities) for other built in CSS utilities.